# Raise I was given is different than the one I was promised

Tags: raise

About 6 months into my job the manager offered me a dollar raise and said it would take effect immediately. I signed a document and he went to give it to my supervisor. He came back and told me that unfortunately I would have to wait until my 1 year anniversary came up before applying the raise. 2 weeks prior to my 1 year anniversary I spoke with both the manager and my supervisor and reminded them about the dollar raise, both said no problem that it had been promised to me. 3 weeks after my anniversary I once again spoke to them about it and now I am only receiving a .50 cent raise even though I signed a document for $1.00. Now my problem is that I do not have a copy of the signed document and I have the feeling they would make up a story if I ask for a copy anyways. So now I am unsure of how to handle this...

Comment: That is a completely different question, not a duplicate.He's not asking how to remind politely remind them of the raise like in the linked question.

Comment: Always get a copy of anything you sign.

Comment: @Daenyth I agree, but a lot of times you trust the other party, specially after one year of working together.

Comment: @S.Nel, have you checked your paystub? maybe they have increased your salary by 1$, but you have jumped to a higher tax bracket or maybe its being deducted for something else. I would just ask my manager carefully and politely.  and then follow up carefully and politely with HR/Accounting.

Comment: @Alex Doesn't matter, always get a copy of anything you sign. There's no reason not to.

Comment: @Daenyth, I agree but I don't blame the OP.

Comment: I didn't say it was OP's fault -- at best the company is being incompetent or misguided, at worst they're exploiting him. I'm just saying that it's something critically important.

Comment: @Daenyth, you are correct . THis is much easier to adjudicate when you can go them letter in hand and assume they mistakenly gave you the wrong amount. It is a good lesson for the future.

Comment: OP, is your resume up to date?